# Finding and return values with associated rows on excel on multiple pages

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks in advance for any help! I haven't used much VBA in excel and can't work out how to do what I need, however I believe I need it to achieve the function I need within the workbook.

I have 31 data pages, in which I need to find if certain information is present and display it on a summary page.

I need is to check if there are values in the column AQ, If there is then I need the data returned in that row in columns E, F and G.
There could be multiple instances per sheet or none per sheet.

Hopefully this will example explain it better:

```
           E         F            G          ...        AQ
          Date      Name      Location               Exception
2       1-12-17     Dave      England
3       1-12-17    Sarah       Wales                   Exp
```

In the example data above the information I would want returned on the Summary page is from row 3. (This type of data is on each of the 31 other pages)

Hope this makes sense! Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you re-organized AQ to be in column A you could use a V-lookup without needing VBA.

Comment: What have you tried? Better to include your efforts rather than expecting everything to be done for you. There are functions such as COUNTIF and tools such as pivot tables which may help you here.

Comment: I have tried without using VBA, but even when I asked on here in a previous question the only response I received was that its not possible without VBA. Reordering the columns is not a viable option.

Comment: As @SJR said, you should make an attempt and provide what you have tried so far. Even if its miles from what you actually want to achieve. Just to give you a starting point, you can achieve this with a simple UDF that filters your column `AQ` to show only rows that have a value.. then transpose that on to your summary sheet

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways you could tackle this problem, for example, pivot tables with specific filter conditions, a UDF that finds the matches and prints them to the output you'd like, etc. In general, it's not a bad idea to use the `Range.Find` method and loop through all the matches.

This requires a certain amount of programming time and energy, which not everyone has, although most people who use Excel a lot eventually end up using `vLookup` a lot. I've always been unsatisfied with `vLookup`, it's so limited compared to the vba `Range.Find` method. Just for you, since it's almost Christmas and I ran out of work that I'm actually paid to do, here's a little gem that should help solve your problem.

It's a UDF lookup that allows you specify which number match to return, and return a custom offset in rows or column to retrieve as a value. Incrementing the variable `matchNum` will give you all the matches in the range, and you can return whatever columns you want using the appropriate amount of offset.

The use of the `Range.Find` method should give you an idea of how you could use code to populate a worksheet with exactly what you wanted without using a UDF lookup function. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

```
'################################################################################################################################
' findwhat: the value you want to find. (needle)
' where: the range you want to look for findwhat (haystack)
' matchNum: if the needle is found more than once in the haystack, find the nth target.
' rowoffset: offset your return value from the target, positive will return the value of the cell below the target.
' columoffset: offset your return value from the target, positive will return the value of the cell to the right of the target.
'################################################################################################################################
Public Function powerLookup(findwhat As Variant, where As Range, Optional matchNum As Long = 1, Optional rowOffset As Long = 0, Optional columnOffset As Long = 0) As Variant
    Dim rngResult As Range, firstAddress As String
    Set rngResult = Nothing
    On Error GoTo Errorhandler ' if something breaks return #NA (will definitely happen if first find call fails)
    Do While matchNum > 0 'loop through the matches until there are no matches or we've reached the target matchnumber
        'the first time, rngResult will be Nothing, so the first find can't have rngResult as an input.
        With where
            If rngResult Is Nothing Then
                Set rngResult = .find(findwhat, , xlValues)
                firstAddress = rngResult.Address 'keep this to know if we've looped past the start
            Else
                'if rngResult is not nothing we've already found a match, find the next match until matchnum is 0
                Set rngResult = .find(findwhat, rngResult, xlValues)
                If rngResult.Address = firstAddress Then
                    'if we reach the first address we've looped around, no more matches found, throw #NA error
                    powerLookup = CVErr(xlErrNA)
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        End With
        matchNum = matchNum - 1
    Loop
    powerLookup = rngResult.offset(rowOffset, columnOffset).Value 'offset the output
    Exit Function
Errorhandler:
   powerLookup = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for this! This is nearly exactly what I after, however the argument for the range it does not seem to accept a range which includes pages as well as cells - is that correct?

Comment: @hsquared Can you post what you were trying to input as the range? A Range is local to a single worksheet, it can't span worksheets.

Comment: that's what I wanted to check - Ideally I wanted something that could span worksheets but It seems that is not possible. (its because the first instance might not be on the first few sheets, or not on every sheet, so could create a lot of unwanted #NAs between values with having to check and return every sheet separately).

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible - but because my sheet names are consecutive numbers, is it possible to loop through within the function adding one to the sheet reference of _where_ ? The range I'm using is '1'!$AQ$3:$AQ$209 - does that make sense?

Comment: You can always use `INDIRECT` to turn a string into a range; alternatively you can loop through sheets using the `Workbook.Sheets()` collection.